# Rijndael encryption using Nodejs getting error like Unsupported key size: NaN bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, rijndael

I am working in Nodejs, Encrypts the data using the Rijndael algorithm with `rijndael-js` but am getting an error as `Unsupported key size: NaN bit`

the code that I implement is mentioned below.

```js
const Rijndael = require("rijndael-js");

// Key can be 16/24/32 bytes long (128/192/256 bit)

const key = { userName: "test@contus.in", password: "admin123" };

// Create Rijndael instance
// `new Rijndael(key, mode)`
const cipher = new Rijndael(key, "cbc");
console.log(cipher);
```

but when I encrypt like this am getting an error

> Unsupported key size: NaN bit

[image: Error]

How to encrypt the object using the Rijndael algorithm?

Answers are really appreciated

Comment: The posted code makes not much sense. First, an incompatible key is used (expected is a 16, 24 or 32 bytes key). Furthermore, neither the plaintext nor the IV are specified and the `encrypt` function is not called. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rijndael-js#usage) is an example of how to encrypt using _rijndael-js_. You might just want to know how objects are encrypted. These must first be converted into a suitable format, e.g. into a string using JSON.

Comment: What is IV actually?

Comment: IV means [initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_(IV)). Most operation modes, such as [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)), expect one. It ensures that if plaintext and key are identical, a different ciphertext is generated for each encryption.